# How can I monitor which files a specific program changes?

Tags: process, monitoring

The problem I wish to solve: I need to figure out where in my system a specific program stores its files. I thought there might be a way for me to monitor which files this program changes. Is this possible?

Comment: Can `lsof -n -p programPid` do the job?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strace`. Read `man strace` and do:

```
strace -e trace=open specific_program
```